# Pass a file containing sqoop commands in oozie workflow

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie

Oozie workflow.xml has command , arg and file xml tags for passing sqoop related commands.

**Is there a way to read/declare a file containing complete sqoop script without using either command or arg tag ?**

something like the below code that we do in case of hive action, where we pass a hive script as file.

```
 <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/hive"/>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                <value>my-hive-default.xml</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <script>script.q</script>
        <param>INPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/input-data/table</param>
        <param>OUTPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/hive</param>
    </hive>
```

Can you please share a workflow.xml corresponding to this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html) - no, there is no way. Try to use [shell action](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/DG_ShellActionExtension.html) to run `sqoop` command with appropriate parameters.

Comment: shell action is the only alternative . I thought of it. Is there any other way to use sqoop action itself.